# How should one read the s*(t) function in Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I'm self-teaching logic and doing it by means of following Elliot Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic (6th edition). In p.56 he defines a a function s* which, in his words, 'assigns to each term t of L an element s*(t) in the domain D'.

For variables and individual constants, I understand the definition. But things get a bit sketchy when it comes to the function letters.

He says: If $f_k^n$ is a function letter, $(f_k^n)^M$ is the corresponding operation in D, and $t_1$, ... , $t_n$ are terms, then

s* $f^n_k$($t_1$, ..., $t_n$)) = ($f^n_k)$$^M$ (s*(t$_1$),...,s*($t_n$))

This function is used to define the notion of satisfiability (which, in turn, is used to define truth in Tarskian terms) and I'm having some problem understanding it. If anyone who's familiar with the text could help me I'd be very thankful.

*n is the number of arguments taken by the function letter, and k is simply an index number

Comment: Should what you write as "f(n,k)M" be read as $f^{n,k}_M$?

Comment: And are the rules for variables and individual constants something like $s^*(x) = s(x)$ and $s^*(c^k) = c^k_M$?

Comment: Sorry for leaving the text unformatted, I've just corrected it to match the notation in the book. The other rules are these: 

1. If t is a variable $x_j$, let s*(t) be $s_j$.
2. If t is an individual constant $a_j$, then s*(t) is the interpretation $(a_j)$$^M$ of this constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an *interpretation* with *domain* $D$ that gives to the "basic" syntactical objects of the language $\mathcal L$ a "meaning" :

- to every *constant* symbol $a_i$ a *denotation* $(a_i)^M$, that is an objcet of $D$
- to every *predicate* letter $A_j^n$ an $n$-place *relation* in $D$
- to every *function* letter $f_j^n$ an $n$-place *operation* in $D$.

A *variable* assignment function $s$ assign to every variabke $x_i$ an object $s(x_i) \in D$, i.e. a sort of "temporary" denotation.

With $s$ we can extend this "temporary" denotation to all *terms* with *variables* inside : this is the "gist" of $s^*$.

Consider e.g. the first-order language of *arithmetic* with two *constants* $0$ and $1$ and two *opeartion* symbols : $+$ and $\times$ and the usual interpretation with domain $\mathbb N$.

The denotation of the two *constants* are : the *numbers* *zero* and *one*, respectively, while to the two *function* symbols are assigned the *operations* of *sum* and *product* between natural numbers, respectively.

The expression :

> $x_1+0$

is a *term* with a variable inside and thus, by himself, it has no denotation.

Consider now the variable assignment function $s$ such that :

> $s(x_1)=0, s(x_2)=1, \ldots$.

What is :

> $s^*(x_1+0)$ ?

It is the object of $\mathbb N$ (i.e. a *natural* number) "calculated" applying the operation of *sum* to the number $0$ (i.e. $s(x_1)$) with itself, i.e.

> $0+0=0$.

If instead we consider the new term $x_2+0$, the same $s$ "induces" a denotation $s^*(x_2+0)=1$, because $s(x_2)=1$.

Comment: This was a great answer, now I understand what he means by the s* function. Thank you for your time.